# how do i convert byte array to long in android

Tags: java, android

I need to convert a `byte[]` of size 4 to type long for my Android app. I found a function `byteArrayToLong(byte_array)` which is in the `java.io.Bits` package, but it isn't working in my application.

Are there any other alternative functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.nio.ByteBuffer`:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {50, -106, 40, -22};
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
System.out.println(buffer.getLong());
```

#### Edit

Of course, @Kaito is right: you need an array of 8 bytes instead. Also, as others mentioned, you may choose an order in which your bytes will be read (`BIG_ENDIAN` by default):

```
    byte[] data = new byte[] {50, -106, 40, -22, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    System.out.println(buffer.getLong()); // 3645145933890453504
    buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    System.out.println(buffer.getLong()); // 3928528434
```

Also, why to prefer an API method? For the sake of simplicity: instead of recognizing byte to long conversion in bitwise shifts you can read what happens here in plain English.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether your first byte is the least or the most significant byte.

**If 1st byte is most significant**:

```
long val = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < YourByte.length; i++)
{
   val = (val << 8) + (YourByte[i] & 0xff);
}
```

**If 1st byte is the least significant byte**:

```
long val = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < YourByte.length; i++)
{
   val += ((long) YourByte[i] & 0xffL) << (i*8);
}
```

**Edit**:

Use `BigInteger` instead of `long` when dealing with more than 8 bytes.

Comment: I just realized from Kaito's answer that if you need to do this where you have more than 8 bytes, you can use BigInteger instead of long.

Answer (score 2):

THE DOCTOR's answer works, but I'd do it *sans* the loop.

For little-endian (the most likely case):

```
long val = b[0] | ((int)(b[1]) << 8) | ((int)(b[2]) << 16) | ((int)(b[3]) << 24);
```

For big-endian:

```
long val = b[3] | ((int)(b[2]) << 8) | ((int)(b[1]) << 16) | ((int)(b[0]) << 24);
```

Also, keep in mind that Java `long` is 8 bytes long. For 4 bytes, an `int` is sufficient.

Comment: the other thing which i thought was first to convert a byte array to type string and then using parse to convert it back to long,currently am working on this approach and am getting some errors and am also skeptic whether it would work or not.

Comment: If you're asking such a question - won't work. Getting ASCII representation involved is too much.

Comment: Yes,i had the same doubt in my mind,now am using ANDREY'answer and its working fine.

Comment: An Int might not be enough. Java supports only singed numbers so an unsigned 4 byte int may not fit in Java's Int.

Comment: To me the little-endian one only worked this way:
`long val = (b[0] & 0xff) | ((b[1] & 0xff) << 8) | ((b[2] & 0xff) << 16) | ((b[3] & 0xff) << 24)`

Answer (score 1):

Three options come to mind:

1. Pass the array to the BigInteger constructor then fetch the long value from the BigInteger
2. Pad the array with another 4 bytes and use ByteBuffer.wrap then getLong
3. Construct it manually by shifting each byte into place.

Depending on the endianness you may have to reverse the array.

Comment: can u please show how would you proceed with the first option?

Comment: new java.math.BigInteger(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1}).longValue()

Answer (score 0):

When converting a **byte[ ]** of **size less than 8 bytes** to type **long**

`public static ByteBuffer byteArraytoByteBuffer(int capacity,byte[] array)
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity).put(array).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        buffer.rewind();
        return  buffer;
    }`

then

`byte[] input = new byte[]{1,0,0,0};

long value = byteArraytoByteBuffer(8,input).getLong();`

1.**ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity)** allocates 8 bytes for type long.

buffer = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

2.**put(array)** will place the 4 bytes

buffer = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

```
           ^
           |
```

now the position of buffer is 4

3.Byte order cab be **LITTLE_ENDIAN** or **BIG_ENDIAN** based on requirement.

4.**buffer.rewind()** Rewinds the buffer and position is set to zero,

buffer = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

```
       ^
       |
```

if buffer.rewind() operation is not done an buffer underflow will occur.Because the position is at 4, when getLong() is called it takes start index as 4.

The same code can be used to convert byte[ ] to int

`byte[] input = new byte[]{1,0,0,0};

long value = byteArraytoByteBuffer(4,input).getInt();`